Can you integrate $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^3}{e^x-1}dx$ using Feyman's technique?
Here is the integral:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^3}{e^x-1}dx$$
Is this integral possible using Feyman's technique. I'm aware that it is solvable as it is a type of Bose integral. However, I'm curious as to whether this can be solved without the knowledge of the Gamma function and the zeta function?
I've already tried it but I cannot find the correct variable placement. Any help would be appreciated.

Is there some reason you want to use the technique Feynman attributed to Woods, which was probably introduced by Euler?

Sort of, I am fond of this approach where we do use differentiation under the integral sign, but it is an indirect solution.
Let
$$
I(a) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x e^{-ax}}{1-e^{-x}} dx, \qquad a > 0.
$$
Since $e^{-x} < 1$ on $(0,\infty)$ we can use the taylor series for $\frac{1}{1-y}$ where $y=e^{-x}$  (this trick can also be used to solve your integral easily but the following approach is more powerful). We can then use Fubini’s to switch the series and integral to obtain
\begin{align*}
I(a) &= \int_{0}^\infty x e^{-ax} \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nx} dx \\
     &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^\infty x e^{-(n+a)x} dx.
\end{align*}
After computing this integral with partial integration we get
$$
I(a) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+a)^2}.
$$
Now we compute the $k$’th derivative of $I$ w.r.t. $a$
\begin{align*}
I^{(k)}(a)&=(-1)^k\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{k+1}e^{-ax}}{1-e^{-x}} dx \\
&= (-1)^k \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(k+1)!}{(n+a)^{2+k}}.
\end{align*}
This yields for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $a>0$
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{k+1}}{e^{ax}-e^{(a-1)x}} dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(k+1)!}{(n+a)^{2+k}}.
$$
And if $a=1$,
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{k+1}}{e^{x}-1} dx = \zeta(2+k)(k+1)!,
$$
which equals $\frac{\pi^4}{15}$ for $k=2$.
